Why does Postman see cookies returned by Laravel, but Flask does not, even when passing through Flask?
I'm working on a project where I'm integrating a Laravel API with a Flask application. Both Laravel and Flask are running inside Docker containers on the same network. My goal is to make a request from Flask to a Laravel endpoint and then handle the cookies returned by Laravel.
Specifically, I'm trying to retrieve the XSRF-TOKEN cookie by sending a GET request to Laravel's /sanctum/csrf-cookie route. When I send this request directly from Postman to Laravel, I receive a 204 No Content status, but I can see that the response includes several cookies, including XSRF-TOKEN.
Here’s the issue I’m facing:
When I make the same request through Flask using requests.Session, Laravel correctly returns a 204 No Content status along with cookies, but Flask is unable to detect or access any of these cookies in the response.
Since Flask can't find the expected cookie, I intentionally return a 404 Not Found from my Flask route to indicate this. However, when I inspect the same request in Postman, it shows the cookies returned by Laravel, even though Flask couldn’t access them.
Here’s a simplified version of my Flask code:
@main.route('/test', methods=['GET'])
def test():
    external_response = session.get(f"{API_URL}/sanctum/csrf-cookie")
    
    print("Status Code:", external_response.status_code)
    print("Cookies:", external_response.cookies)
    
    xsrf_token = external_response.cookies.get('XSRF-TOKEN')
    
    if xsrf_token:
        return jsonify({"XSRF-TOKEN": xsrf_token}), 200
    else:
        return jsonify({"error": "XSRF-TOKEN not found"}), 404

To summarize:

Flask sends a request to Laravel, which returns a 204 No Content status along with cookies.
Flask is unable to see or access the cookies in Laravel’s response.
Due to this, my Flask route returns a 404, but Postman can still see the cookies that Laravel sent.

My questions are:

Why does Postman show the cookies returned by Laravel, but Flask cannot access them, even though Flask makes the same request?
How can I properly access these cookies in Flask, given that Laravel returns a 204 status?
I've checked for HttpOnly flags and inspected the headers, but I'm still unsure why Flask behaves differently from Postman in this case.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

If the laravel endpoint is maintained by you, maybe check what data the incoming requests send from both postman and flask. Im pretty sure there is a difference in their request data which makes the difference here. Also verify you are using https as not doing this might omit some data(like session related data) as its not secure
